# Transform a 3D face coordinates to 2D.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How can I transform the points on a 3D face of a cube in coordinates (x,y,z) into a 2D coordinates (x',y')?
I need to convert the 8 points shown in the figure that are in 3D coordinates into 2D.
Any sugestions?

The figure represent a simple example. In my problem the cube can be in any position on space.

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Svr.jpg)

Comment: The example does not give us enough information to figure out exactly what it is that you're trying to do. Are you trying to project the coordinates of the cube onto a plane parallel to a given face of the cube? Are you trying to describe a global projection onto a specific plane? It might help if you could explain how you want to use the 2D coordinates.

Comment: I want to put a specific face of a cube with the same z coordinates.

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: Transform the 3D face to a 2D space.

Comment: Now you're just repeating what you already said in your original post, which as I explained in my first comment is unclear.

Comment: How is underclear? Did you see the Figure?

Comment: I did see the figure. Here are very specific examples of what is unclear: in the 2D coordinates, is the distance between $1$ and $2$ the same as the distance between $1$ and $2$ in 3D space? Do we always know where exactly the points lie on the face? Do we necessarily have the coordinates of the corners of the face?

Comment: Also, is this a process that you are trying to implement on a computer? Could we use commands from a programming language such as Matlab?

Comment: Yes its for computation, but i dont want matlab functions i need to calculate myself. The face doesn't change. The new coordinates lies on a new reference x',y'. Since its a face we can use only a x',y'  instead of x,y,z. Basically  what I know that i need to calculate a new basis and recalculate the coordinates but dont understand how.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess at your question is as follows: you are given several coordinates. You know a priori that these coordinates lie on the same face of a cube, i.e. that they lie on the same plane in $3$-space.  We are also given the coordinates to a point which we know is the bottom-left corner (i.e. 1 in the figure), coordinates of a point on the bottom edge of the face (like 2), and coordinates a point 8 on the left edge of the face.

The goal is to write 2D coordinates associated with these points corresponding to the apparent coordinates when one looks from an angle normal to the face of the cube.

Let $P_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$ denote the coordinates of the $i$th point. It suffices to calculate
$$
u_1 = P_{2} - P_1, \quad v_1 = \frac{u_1}{\|u_1\|}, \quad u_2 = P_8 - P_1, \quad v_2 = \frac{u_2}{\|u_2\|}
$$
where $\|(x,y,z)\| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$. We can then calculate the coordinates of the point $P$ in these 2D coordinates as
$$
X' = u_1 \cdot (P - P_1), \quad Y' = u_2 \cdot (P - P_1),
$$
where $u \cdot v$ denotes the [dot-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition).

Comment: It works fine! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please be a bit clearer in the future so that we don't have to guess what you're looking for.